# SQL - How to use a foreign key from parent in child?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to copy (automatically) or add a constraint that forces a child record to use the same foreign key that its parent record is using.

Example:

```
Company Table
-----------------
Id | Name
-------------
1  | Pepsi
2  | Coke


Department Table
------------------------
Id | Name           | CompanyId
----------------------------
1  | Human Resources|  1
2  | Sales          |  2

Employee Table
------------------------
Id | Name           |  DepartmentId |  CompanyId
------------------------------------------------
1  | Bob            |  1            |  X
2  | Jim            |  2            |  X
```

In the employee table, I want there to be a constraint that X must be the same as the CompanyId in DepartmentId.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is:  Don't store the company id in the `employee` table.  Always look it up through the department.   That is the "correct" solution.

If you have a reason to duplicate this data, you can manage that with a unique constraint/index and a foreign key to both columns.

```
alter table department add constraint unq_department_company_department
    unique (companyId, departmentId);
```

You can then use this for the foreign key:

```
alter table employee add constraint fk_employee_department
    foreign key (companyId, departmentId) references department(companyId departmentId);
```

Comment: Yes I would have preferred to avoid it too but it got deeply nested. Obviously the example is much simpler. Thank you!